# How can i run an intellij project in eclipse/sts?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to work on a school project with a friend who works in intelliJ. I just cloned his project repo but I am not sure how to go about running/testing the app as the file structure is slightly different and I cannot right click and run as spring boot app like I can with my projects created in spring tool suite. Is there anyway to run the project without having him export as eclipse in intellij?(All of my research leads me to that answer otherwise)

Comment: If you are using old version of IntelliJ IDEA, you need to install a plugin for supporting gradle else last version of IntelliJ IDEA comes added,  according this link  https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/spring-boot/ and you should work easily. Just open project from name root.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on the dependency and build management technology that you use for the project. If you use Maven, you can import the project in STS using the `Import Existing Maven Project...` import wizard. If you use Gradle, you need to install the Buildship support for Gradle for Eclipse and then import the project as existing Gradle project.

If you don't use any dependency resolution and build technology, and instead defined your dependencies manually in the project configuration, I am not aware of any way to import an existing IntelliJ project into Eclipse/STS as is. You can import the project from the file system as a new project in Eclipse/STS and then configure the dependencies, source folders, output folders, etc. manually. That should work for most project structures. But I would highly recommend to switch over to use a build/dependency management solution, it is way easier than doing everything manually yourself.